# How to remove unused application from the menu but not completely uninstall it on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, default-programs, context-menu

What I wanna do is not to uninstall certain apps but to completely hide it. For example I'm using VLC I didn't want to uninstall the default Movie Player, but I didn't want to have it run my videos either. 
The problem with this app was that even if VLC was set as default video player on double click Movie Player started to play videos.
My solution for above mentioned problem was right click on video, properties tab, choosing VLC from list of recommended apps and setting it as default choice, however I had to repeat it different times (for each video type)

Any suggestions how to force system to use my choice of apps. Something more global as solution where I don't have to do workarounds but just set my system to use the apps I want.

Comment: If I am right you can set the *Default Applications* somewhere in the System settings.

Comment: Therefore: System Settings → Details → Default Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a [link](http://www.libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-ubuntu-linux)…

Please refer there to

> Change the default app for multiple filetypes?

although this is a terminal-based solution, it's more specific.

Comment: Thanks terminal based solution helped with part of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Am not so sure what you mean by 'not to uninstall certain apps but to hide it'. Please give me more on this.
About the video player issue, I have two suggestions:

1. Open up your system settings by launching dash and searching for 'system settings'. At the bottom, there is the System section and inside a 'Details' icon. Click on it to view details about your computer. On the left side there is a sidebar, click on the 'Default Applications' menu and you can set your default application for different media including video. VLC should be in the video select and all you have to do is select it.
2. If you have installed Ubuntu tweak, you can use it to set default applications for different media types. This is for Ubuntu tweak 0.8.5. Launch up Ubuntu Tweak by searching for it in the dash, go to the admin tab on top, and then select 'File Type Manager'. On the right, there is a sidebar with different media types - Audio, Text, Video, Application and Image. Choose video and then select VLC as the default media player for the video types you want.

Hope I have helped.

Comment: Thanks upper solution for some obscure reason didn't work so I set it manually. m not fan of ubuntu tweak alike apps so not using it.

Comment: What I wanna do is not delete the default apps installed with fresh installation of ubuntu, reason is simple the default installation is an intertwined system dependent on shared supporting files, making the operating system stable, I simply wanna have these unneeded apps hidden and use the ones I installed, Zimbra instead of Thunderbird, Nightingale instead of Rhythmbox etc. I wanna hide unused application from the menu, but not remove it from the system

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `System settings - Details - Default applications`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but setting VLC as default did not give wanted results as mentioned in question I had to set the default player manually. Mentioned solution on double click will start Movie Player and not VLC.